# How to compare array of objects to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and array of strings

```
cities = [ { id: '1', name: 'Paris'}, { id: '2', name: 'Rome'}, { id: '3', name: 'London'}, { id: '4', name: 'Barcelona'}]

userChoice = ['2','4']
```

I need to iterate over cities with userChoice and find name of cities by id.
I guess it's going to be a nested loop, but I am strugling with it.

```
cities.filter(city=> userChoice.forEach(choice => choice == city.id))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter `cities` array by checking if a city's `id` is present in `userChoice` array.

To get just the names, you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform the result.

```js
let cities = [ { id: '1', name: 'Paris'}, { id: '2', name: 'Rome'}, { id: '3', name: 'London'}, { id: '4', name: 'Barcelona'}];
let userChoice = ['2','4'];

let filteredCities = cities.filter(city => userChoice.includes(city.id));

let names = filteredCities.map(city => city.name);

console.log(names);
```

Comment: `includes()` doesn't work on IE. If you want to make it work on all the devices and browsers, it would be better to use `indexOf()`. i.e `userChoice.indexOf(city.id) > -1`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object to look up ID based on city.

```
let cityMap = new Map(cities.map(c => [c.name, c.id]));
console.log(cityMap.get("Rome")); // --> "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple map, you map the array element to the city from the other array. You might want to put a null check in if you can have values that might not be in the array but for simplicity I left it out.

```js
const cities = [ { id: '1', name: 'Paris'}, { id: '2', name: 'Rome'}, { id: '3', name: 'London'}, { id: '4', name: 'Barcelona'}];

const userChoice = ['2','4'];

const userCities  = userChoice.map(val => cities.find(c => c.id === val).name);

console.log(userCities)
```

Comment: `cities.find(c => c.id === val).name` will get a reference error when there is no city with an id in userChoice. It should handle that exception.

Comment: I have mentioned that "You might want to put a null check in if you can have values that might not be in the array but for simplicity I left it out."